# How to ssh from windows to my ubuntu machine in the local network

Tags: networking, windows, ssh

When I'm trying to ssh to my local ubuntu server from the gitbash on my windows machine Im getting this error:

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.11
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.11 port 22: Bad file number
```

Other answers I've found seems to be related to linux-to-linux connetions. I'm newbie here, can you please provide information how to achieve that?

Running `nmap -sS 192.168.1.11 -p 22`:

```
C:\Users\Me>nmap -sS 192.168.1.11 -p 22

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org )
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.11
Host is up (0.0040s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
MAC Address: 20:16:D8:3E:E0:30 (Liteon Technology)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.70 seconds
```

Running: `ssh -v 192.168.1.11 -p 443`:

```
$ ssh -v 192.168.1.11 -p 443
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Me/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for 192.168.1.11
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.11 [192.168.1.11] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.11 port 443: Attempt to connect timed out w
ithout establishing a connection
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.11 port 443: Bad file number
```

And even if I edit my `.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host ubuntu.dev
Hostname 192.168.1.11
User meubuntu
```

And connecting to `ssh ubuntu.dev` It still does not work

Comment: could you update the question with output of `nmap -sS 192.168.1.11 -p 22` and `nc -z 192.168.1.11 1-25 -v` or just scan port `22` with any of the port scanners and update the question with the outout

Comment: @Stormvirux, updated

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but it came up sorta high up in the Google search, so, for anyone having troubles for SSH'ing from a Windows to a Linux box, in my case, the problem was that I hadn't installed the SSH server on my Linux Mint machine.

Even if you **do** have SSH installed (like for connecting to another computers), you need this package to enable receiving connections.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: This helped me in setting up ssh connection between my windows 7 host and ubuntu guest.

Answer (score 0):

From your `nmap` output

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

You can see the State of `port 22` is set as filtered meaning its being blocked either by your ISP or by some firewall. We can use `port 443` for doing ssh which wont be blocked by ISP or firewall as folllows.

```
ssh -v 192.168.1.11 -p 443
```

This will connect to ssh using `port 443`.

For more ways to do this see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number).

Comment: Ive already tried it, does not work. Turned off my antivirus and its firewall - still does not work. Maybe I need something to setup on my ubuntu machine?